# How to handle N/A values in SQlite?

Tags: r, sqlite

How can we use SQL functions as AVG on N/A values directly from the database?

```
"SELECT relig, 
 AVG(age) as avg_age, 
 AVG(tvhours) as avg_tvhours, 
 count(*) as n, 
 FROM gss_cat
 GROUP BY relig"
```

The following cannot be used in SQLite, due to the N/A values in the dataset.

Comment: Can you show the full R script?  `N/A` has no special semantic meaning in SQLite.  I presume you mean that some data frame in R has `NA` values?

Comment: This is what i have inserted. `gss_cat1 <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT relig, 
                                                 avg(age) AS avg_age, 
                  AVG(CASE WHEN tvhours <> 'N/A' THEN tvhours ELSE END), 
                 COUNT(*) AS n, 
                 FROM gss_cat 
GROUP BY relig")`. I get the following error **"error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ")": syntax error**".

Comment: Remove the comma in `COUNT(*) AS n`

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports null which is used as an NA.  Using the builtin BOD data frame.

```
BOD$Time[6] <- NA
BOD$Time
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA

library(sqldf)

mean(BOD$Time, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 3
sum(BOD$Time, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 15

sqldf("select avg(Time), sum(Time) from BOD")
##   avg(Time) sum(Time)
## 1         3        15
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you are asking about SQLite, and not R.  Assuming you have `N/A` values in some of your columns, you can still make your query work by averaging over a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    relig,
    AVG(CASE WHEN age <> 'N/A' THEN age ELSE NULL END) AS avg_age,
    AVG(CASE WHEN tvhours <> 'N/A' THEN tvhours ELSE END) AS avg_tvhours,
    COUNT(*) AS n
FROM gss_cat
GROUP BY relig;
```

This should work because `AVG` ignores `NULL` values in SQLite.  So, by replacing `N/A` with `NULL` we effectively remove it from the calculation.

Comment: Hello Tim. 
I get the following error: 

Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ")": syntax error

I use SQlite inside R: the following query: 
dbGetQuery(connection, "SQL query")

Comment: @Noori11 Sorry, I had stray comma in the query.  Try it again.